# Firebug: object not found, what is my wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i tried this code with alert so ilceid var contains data. when i change selectbox, nothing happens and firebug says: `object not found`... 
what's my wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#ilce').change(function(){
        var ilceid = $('#ilce').val();
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'ilce/ajax',
        data:'ilceid='+ilceid,
        success:function(output){
            $('#semt').html(output);
        }
    });
    });   
});
```

Comment: Which line is throwing this error?

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: jquery-1.9.1.min.js .. PScoder there is no error throwing..

Answer (score 1):

There is  only chance of error here-

```
 $('#semt').html(output);
```

please ensure semt is in the html.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe in some older jQuery, but now jQuery just does nothing if you do this on non existent element. Edit: maybe it is a matter of old jQuery

Comment: @Piyas De, it's in... there is no wrong... by the way: http://yigitozmen.com/CI/index.php/ilce this code runs here but in local doesnt.....

Answer (score 0):

Try with

[jQuery.parseJSON( json )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.

Comment: that code runs in remote http://yigitozmen.com/CI/index.php/ilce please check.. but does not run in local.. i'm using easyphp.. is that buggy?